# How to convert a given length in centimeter and represent it as a combination of kilometers, meters and centimeters?

Tags: java

I need to get a centimeter number input by the user, and then representing it as a combination of kilometers, meters, and centimeters. For example, 1005020 centimeters will be 10km, 50meters, and 20 centimeters.

I just started out and I feel It's a really basic question and I feel so frustrated.

I've tried to code and unfortunately can't reach the desired result

```
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
 System.out.println("This program takes centimeter number and represent it as a combination of kilometer, meter, and centimeter");
 System.out.println("Please enter centimeters:");
 double centimeters = scanner.nextDouble();
 double convertedCentimeters = centimeters;

 double kilometers = (int) (convertedCentimeters / 100000);
 convertedCentimeters /= 100000;
 double meters = (int)(convertedCentimeters / 100);
 convertedCentimeters /= 100;
```

It will print 10km and 0.0 meters and 0.10050200000000001 centimeters.
I've tried without casting and km is wrong, tried to put everything as int and still wrong. I will really appreciate the help, I need to win this one. If you can lead me to the solution and not tell me it directly that will be great.

Answer (score 3):

The major thing missing from your answer is use of the *modulus*, which you need to correctly answer your question.  Consider the following working script:

```
int centimeters = 1005020;
int kilometers = centimeters / 100000;
int meters = (centimeters % 10000) / 100;
int centimetersFinal = centimeters % 100;
```

Given that you want to report whole numbers for each unit, I recommend starting off and working with integers everywhere.  This also makes the arithmetic much easier.

The kilometer value is obtained by just taking the floor of the centimeter amount converted to kilometers.  In this case, we get 10km, what you expect, but we don't include the remainder, because that goes to the meter and centimeter components.

The meter value takes the mod 10000 to isolate only the components that are strictly *less* than one kilometer.  Then, we divide by 100 to remove the centimeter component.

Finally, the centimeter component is just the remainder when dividing the original amount by 100.

Comment: Thank you so much. your explanation is so clear! thank you sir